# Structuring HTML form output

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, forms

I have an HTML form with JSON output structured as so:

```html
<form>
  <input name="a1">
  <input name="a2">
  <input name="a3">
  <input name="b1">
  <input name="b2">
  <input name="b3">
  <input name="c1">
  <input name="c2">
  <input name="c3">
</form>
```

```json
{
  "a1": "some value",
  "a2": "another value",
  "a3": "yet another value",
  "b1": "some value",
  "b2": "another value",
  "b3": "yet another value",
  "c1": "some value",
  "c2": "another value",
  "c3": "yet another value"
}
```

but I'd like it to be sorted like this:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "1": "some value",
    "2": "another value",
    "3": "yet another value"
  },
  "b": {
    "1": "some value",
    "2": "another value",
    "3": "yet another value"
  },
  "c": {
    "1": "some value",
    "2": "another value",
    "3": "yet another value"
  }
}
```

My Question: **In the HTML**, is there a way to structure the form to make the JSON output show up like that when I send it to my server? I'm using NodeJS for my server. Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: That’s not sorting. What is your current code? What have you tried?

Comment: Looks like valid JSON to me, `JSON.stringify(object)` then `JSON.parse(ajaxString)`

Comment: @StackSlave How is this related to the question? The question is about restructuring an object.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

Comment: For starter, use `name="a[]"` syntax in html. then at server side, iterate `req.body.a` to get `a[]` elements and indexes, so you can create json.

Answer (score 0):

This is how, we're using in **React project**, as you did. just create JSON object and store it in Database wherever you want,

**Example:**

```js
    orderForm: {
      name: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          name: 'name',
          placeholder: 'Your Name'
        },
        value: '',
        label: 'Name',
      },
      street: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          name: 'street',
          placeholder: 'Street'
        },
        value: '',
        label: 'Street',
      },
      zipCode: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          name: 'zipCode',
          placeholder: 'Zip Code'
        },
        value: '',
        label: 'Zip Code',
      },
      country: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          name: 'country',
          placeholder: 'Country'
        },
        value: '',
        label: 'Country',
      }

    },
```

injecting in to HTML, you can take a guess, this's how we create a dynamic form to get data from user.

```js
        
        
const formElementsArray = [];

for (let key in this.state.orderForm) {
  formElementsArray.push({
    id: key,
    config: this.state.orderForm[key]
  });
}

{formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
  <Input
  key={formElement.id}
{...formElement.config} />}
```

**Note:** if you found any issue, just wrap the console, by this you can get.

Happy codin'!

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this

```
<form>
  <input name="a.one">
  <input name="a.two">
  <input name="a.three">
  <input name="b.one">
  <input name="b.two">
  <input name="b.three">
  <input name="c.one">
  <input name="c.two">
  <input name="c.three">
</form>
```

and you'll get an object like this

```
{
  "a": {
    "one": "some value",
    "two": "another value",
    "three": "yet another value"
  },
  "b": {
    "one": "some value",
    "two": "another value",
    "three": "yet another value"
  },
  "c": {
    "one": "some value",
    "two": "another value",
    "three": "yet another value"
  }
}
```

hope this helps. let me know if you have more question.